# How to Hit Test with duplicated object on stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe

Hey everyone so I have my main Movie Clip added to the stage called `mcObstacles` now in this movie clip i have a nested movie clip with an instance name of `mcAsteroidsSpin` this movie clip has 4 rotating asteroids that I use to hit test against my spaceship those 4 rotating asteroids have a hit box named `mcSpinningHit` now everything is working fine as far as the hitTestObject functions goes against all 4 of the nested movie clips. The issue that I am struggling with is that when I try and Duplicate that `mcAsteroidsSpin` movie clip that is on the stage and run the game again it only hitTests againts the duplicate Movie clip instance. I have tried multiple ideas like adding all the duplicate movie clips to an array and hit test then but didn't work for me or maybe set it up wrong. Instead I resorted to renaming the duplicate `mcAsteroidsSpin` to `mcAsteroidsSpin2` and `mcAsteroidsSpin3` and so on and making multiple functions. Which i know is the hard way and there is an easier method I am over looking here is how I Have it setup and any help would be appreciated!

```
  //MAIN OBSTACLES HANDLER LOOP INNER IS EVERYTHING ELSE INSIDE IT
         for (var i:int = 0; i < aObstacleArray.length; i++)
         {
             // Get a platform instance from the Array.
             var aObstacle:mcObstacles = aObstacleArray[i];
             
              /************************SPINNING ASTEROIDS 1************************
                *                                                        *
                **********************************************************/
            
             for (var a:int = 0; a < aObstacle.mcAsteroidsSpin.numChildren; a++)
             {
                 // Get a potential Asteroid.
                 var spinningAsteroids:mcSpinningHit = aObstacle.mcAsteroidsSpin.getChildAt(a) as mcSpinningHit;

                  // Skip if it is not a Asteroid.
                 if (!spinningAsteroids) continue;
         
                 // Ignore wrong Asteroid by name.
                 if (spinningAsteroids.name != "mcSpinningHit") continue;
                 
                 if (spaceship.mcHit.hitTestObject(spinningAsteroids))
                 {
                     spaceship.destroy();
                     trace("HIT");
                 }
                
             }
         }
```

So Pretty much i am trying to hitTest against more than one of `aObstacle.mcAsteroidsSpin` movie clips/

Comment: It is out of the provided snippet, but the possible reason is that you forget to add the duplicate obstacles to your **aObstacleArray**.

Comment: Thats the thing though wouldn't I have to add the `aObstacle.mcAsteroidsSpin` to it's on array and hit test against that? Since I am duplicating the `mcAsteroidsSpin` inside of the Obstacles.  I tried to do something along these lines inside this for loop ` var spinningArray:Array = new Array();
     var aSpinningAsteroid:MovieClip = aObstacle.mcAsteroidsSpin;
     spinningArray.push(aSpinningAsteroid);`

Comment: You have multiple obstacles with multiple nested asteroids. In order to **hitTestObject** all the asteroids you can go two ways. 1. Loop through **all** obstacles then in each iteration loop through all asteroids in current obstacle. You can do it with nested loops (pretty much your code). 2. Have a single array for all asteroids and add all the new asteroids there upon creation. Thus you get a single **Array** to iterate through, no nested loops needed.

Comment: Thanks organis you the man. Ill try that out for sure.